# Combining a list of named records and keeping track of a date field in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a list of records in MS Access e.g.

- **PrimaryKey, RecordName, Date**
- 1, Record1, Jan-16
- 2, Record1, Feb-16
- 3, Record1, Mar-16
- 4, Record1, Dec-16
- 5, Record2, Feb-16
- 6, Record2, Dec-16

I trying to figure out how to manipulate them with SQL such that they appear in the following manner

- **UniqueList of RecordNames, Jan-16, Feb-16, Mar-16, Apr-16, May-16, Jun-16, Jul-16, Aug-16, Sep-16, Oct-16, Nov-16, Dec-16**
- Record1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
- Record2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1

I would like the unique records to be combined and where there is a date for that record a 1 should be indicated.

**Steps/ thought process**

- I know the SQL should look for the max and min dates to determine how many months of fields should be added.
- All fields in the new table should be set to zero by default.
- The next step should be to move through each record in the original table and when it finds a date it should place a 1 in the relevant field in the new table.
- The new table should only have a unique list of record names

  I know how to do this in excel, but at this point, I'm not even sure if it's possible in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create Crosstab query with Date field as Column Hedings and fill "Column Headings" propery of query by desired dates. Something like this:

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Count([ID]) Is Null,0,Count([ID])) AS [Count]
SELECT Table1.RecordName
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.RecordName
PIVOT Format([RecordDate],"mmm-yy") In ("Jan-16","Feb-16","Mar-16","Apr-16","May-16","Jun-16","Jul-16","Aug-16","Sep-16","Oct-16","Nov-16","Dec-16");
```

Here I assumed, that Date field has date/time data type. If you want to see only "1" in results if date falls in selected month instead of count, replace  first row by

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Count([ID]) Is Null,0,1) AS [Flag]
```